# Select specific text within an INPUT text field on change with JQuery Trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have this input text field and I would like to select (highlight really) the first 3 characters, when it changes.

```
<input class="descriptions" value="temp text"/>
```

And I have this script monitoring the onChange event...

```
$(document).on('change','.descriptions',function(event) {
    event.target.focus();
    event.target.setSelectionRange(0,3);
});
```

When I manually change the text in this input text field, the script works. However, when I trigger the event using Jquery and a link, it does NOT:

```
<a onMouseDown="javascript:$('.descriptions').val('test text');
$('.descriptions').trigger('change');">update input</a>
```

I thought they were virtually the same!  I did notice that if I log the `event.target` to the console, the output is not quite exactly the same.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show all your code together, but this code does what you are after:

```js
$('.descriptions').on('change', function(event){
  event.target.focus();
  event.target.setSelectionRange(0,3);
});

$('#lnkChange').on("click", function(){
  $('.descriptions').val("changed text");
  $('.descriptions').trigger("change");
});

$('#btn').on("click", function(){
  $('.descriptions').trigger("change");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="descriptions">
<a href="#" id="lnkChange">Change text of input</a>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Trigger Change Event Only">
```

Comment: Thank you. This indeed worked in the snippet but not on my site.  It turned out the problem was that, when the input value is updated programmatically, you have to wait for a moment to be able to select text within it.  I used `window.setTimeout(function() {)` to pause a beat and it worked.

Comment: @Hank `setTimeout()` should not be necessary at all. I've updated my answer to include a hyperlink as you show in your question, although I've moved all the JavaScript and JQuery out of the HTML (as they should be).

Comment: Thanks again ScottMarcus. I think things on my actual site are complicated by the fact that there are hundreds of these entries and, without relying on specific ids or indexes, things must be getting mixed up in the broad class definition I'm trying to use to access and pair links and inputs.  I'll report back more specifics.

Comment: Yes, I definately think it has to do with using the broad class selector.  When there are more elements in the class, only the value of the last class member is selected.  See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9tr1txvh/

I think I need to work on selecting only the specific input that should be paired with a specific href.